# swing: which fonts to use for better portability?

Tags: swing

I'm writing swing window. I need to display it on several OS (Windows/Linux/Solaris is minimal).
Different controls in my window use different fonts - Tahoma, MS Sans Serif, Monospace and others)

I tried to run my application on Linux and even Microsoft fonts were displayed successfully.

I wonder if there are any guidelines which fonts is better to use in terms of portability? Or it doesn't matter and I can use ANY fonts and they will be displayed on ANY OS?

Thanks

Comment: Well, this would be a typesetting dream come true.

Comment: Why not use default fonts as decided by the `LookAndFeel`?

Comment: @jfpoilpret how to do that? for exampe how to set "14 size bold default lookandfell font"?

Answer (score 2):

I think DIALOG is the only safe font to be guarenteed across all platforms and has always been the font I've used and had success with, though these are claimed to be fully supported: Serif, Sans-serif, Monospaced, Dialog, and DialogInput

Other fonts will likely not work on some given OSs unless you ship the font library with your app.

Comment: Can you add any links to sources of that info?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to let the user decide which fonts they want to use.  Only they really know which one looks best to them.

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/listing-all-available-fonts-provided-in-the-s.html

Comment: it's hard enough to properlly create an application that runs and looks proper on all platforms, worrying about what font a user may or may not pick just complicates everything. on top of that its just a bad user experience to immediately have to choose a font, people don't care as long as it renders fine

Comment: @meverett You're assuming a lot about what I meant.  I just meant to offer the user the choice and never said to force it on them.  Of course you should use sensible defaults.  The OP is worried that the font comes up right and the app is usable.  Offering the ability to configure the font addresses this concern.    Also, if you use a [decent layout manager](http://www.miglayout.com/), offering a font choice is a much easier feature to [build](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t101878.html).